# Is it possible to unlock achievements multiple times on your Windows Live account if you have multiple copies of the game?

Tags: achievements, games-for-windows-live

I have two copies of Batman Arkham Aslyum. A windows live version I bought from WalMart, and a steam version. I've already unlocked all of the achievements with the version I bought from WalMart, but I'm curious if I can unlock all of the achievements again with the Steam version.

If I have two different copies of a game, each with its own unique CD key, and activate both of those games on my Windows Live account, will I be able to unlock the achievements twice?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, if you're using the same GFWL account, it doesn't matter where you got the game from. You'll already have the achievements and will not be able to earn them a second time. Achievements are tied to your GFWL account, not the CD key you use to install the game.

Arkham Asylum is a bit of an exception, however. There are **two separate versions** of this game on GFWL: The original and the Game Of The Year edition. The achievement list for each version is exactly the same, but GFWL considers them two different games and you can earn the achievements for both. (I'm not sure why Microsoft/Warner Bros/Rocksteady did things this way, but it's definitely an exception and not the rule. The GOTY edition of Arkham City [will *not* be a separate game](http://community.batmanarkhamcity.com/forums/showthread.php/16912-Game-of-the-Year-and-Harley-Quinn-s-Revenge-Technical-FAQ).)

The [Batman Franchise Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/15401/) on Steam includes the [GOTY edition of Arkham Asylum](http://store.steampowered.com/app/35140/). If the version you played before was also the GOTY edition, then you've already earned the achievements for that version of the game and won't be able to get them a second time. Otherwise, enjoy your additional 1000 Gamerscore.

Comment: Ok thanks alot i just wosnt sure how that would work i know i have all the achievements for xbox and GFWL that show up on my accound i diddnt know what would happen with a new cd key.

Comment: thanks you just made my day, the first one was not the game of the year edition but one and the steam one is

Comment: +1 for acknowledging that you can get achievements in each of the different versions of Arkham Asylum.